# Create a blank raster from scratch using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

I'm wondering if there is any way to create a raster with no input data aside from an extent and cell size (and possibly a default value).

I'm using QGIS as a way to try my analysis and eventually script it, but just am looking for how to do it in QGIS at the moment.

Comment: Please decide which of QGIS and GDAL you wish to ask about in this particular question. That way your question can focus on what you have researched/tried with respect to using it to answer your own question before posting.

Comment: The QGIS processing toolbox has a "create constant raster" tool which does exactly what you ask for